# How to implement a code for take a list of arguments or a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a MSA(multiple sequence alignment) and I would like to have the sequences as an argument for my Hamming distance function. I got a suggestion to use some itertools stuff. I dont know if i got the right one, but to me seems it is.

I tried this:

```
def hamming_dist(s1, s2):
    assert len(s1) == len(s2)
    hd = 0
    for b1, b2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if b1 != b2:
            hd += 1
    return hd

def imap(function, *iterables):
    iterables = map(iter, iterables)
    while True:
        args = tuple([next(it) for it in iterables])
        print(args)
        if function is None:
            yield tuple(args)
        else:
            yield function(*args)

tup = ('ATGTG', '-TG-G'), ('A-GT-', 'ATG-G')
distances = imap(hamming_dist, *tup)
for dist in distances:
    print(dist)

('ATGTG', 'A-GT-')
2
()
TypeError: hamming_dist() missing 2 required positional arguments: 's1' and 's2'
```

Got this error and I trying to figure out!
I don't understand why imap works ate the first case(first tuple), but failed in the second one.
Maybe because the consumed iter? 
There are any way some of you guys help me to figured out what I am doing wrong!?

Looking more closely I got that imap function returning only one arg(the first tuple, and then the second one is empty. Hummm...

I changed the imap function to:

```
def imap(function, *iterables):
    iterables = map(iter, iterables)
    for it in iterables:
        args = tuple(it)
        if function is None:
            yield tuple(args)
        else:
            yield function(*args)
```

And now its returning the expected answer, but I need a improvement to get all sequences compared against each other. I think I will need something like itertools permutation.

But anyway thank for your time guys.

Sorry to bother you! Lesson learned trying hard before ask.

Thank you for you time.

Paulo

Comment: The function you try to implement is called `starmap` in `itertools`: `starmap(hamming_dist, tup)`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `imap` to:

```
def imap(function, *iterables):
iterables = (x for x in iterables)
while True:
    if function is None:
        yield tuple(args)
    else:
        try:
            yield function(*next(iterables))
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Note, this code is probably not what you want to be using in the bigger picture but it's close to the code you gave. It's not very idiomatic at all.

For instance, why not try mapping `hamming_distace` to your list of iterables?

Answer (score 0):

I got it all figured out like this:

```
def hamming_dist(s1, s2):
    assert len(s1) == len(s2)
    hd = 0
    for b1, b2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if b1 != b2:
            hd += 1
    return hd

def imap(function, *iterables):
    iterables = map(iter, iterables)
    for it in iterables:
        args = tuple(it)
        if function is None:
            yield tuple(args)
        else:
            yield function(*args) 


distances = imap(hamming_dist, *itertools.combinations(ls,2))
for dist in distances:
    print(dist)
```

It gives the right answers in my toy example. I will check with a more real MSA.

Thank you all for your time! If you have a better solution please let me know.

Thanks